# Confusion with それだけ in these lyrics

Tags: translation, usage

Could anyone please help me translate this? I have only gotten a hang of basic sentences but this one I just cannot seem to understand.

> 疑いはいらない。それだけが真実
>   Utagai wa iranai. Sore dake ga shinjitsu.

I am mainly confused about what function それだけ has in this sentence.

Comment: Please remember to tell us what the context is when asking a question like this.  In this case, it seems the quote is from the lyrics to [黒い瞳の魔獣](http://hot-jp-lyrics.com/lyrics/%E9%BB%92%E3%81%84%E7%9E%B3%E3%81%AE%E9%AD%94%E7%8D%A3-%E6%AD%8C%E8%A9%9E-asriel.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example それだけ literally means "that alone" or "only that".  So in the first part the person is stating that they don't want/care about suspicions, after which they go on to say that that's all that matters.

Comment: So, something like "I do not need suspicions, only (want to know) the truth"?

Comment: It's a bit more indirect than that, but yes.  More literally, it's to the effect of "The only truth is that I don't want suspicions."

Comment: 本当にありがとう！You were really helpful!